# SSRS - Link not clickable in .net Report Application

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report that specifies a 'Go to URL' action for a textbox.  The URL I am using is simply a field from the dataset, so the expression for the URL is something like "=Fields!URLLinkText.Value".  When I deploy the report to SSRS Report Manager, the link works fine.  It is clickable and opens the URL.  However, when I link to the report from the custom asp.Net Reporting Application, the link is not clickable.  The cursor of the mouse does not even change when I hover over the link.  It seems like the hyperlink/Go To property of the textbox is completely removed.  At first, I thought that this had to be an issue with the configuration of the reporting app, which was disabling external hyperlinks.  However, I created another report with just one textbox with a Go To Action to go to www.CNN.com and it worked on both the Report Manager and the Report Application...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I was just posting about a possibly related issue.  It does not involve any custom reporting app though.  http://weblogs.asp.net/mnissen/archive/2009/03/26/reporting-services-does-not-display-hyperlink-for-placeholder-with-go-to-url-action.aspx

A few different options you can try: wrap the link in javascript, try "servername:port" instead of the site name if its internal, or try reversing the slashes like http backslash backslash...

Comment: Thanks bnw, I've tried the javascript, as well as applying the Go To properties to both the expression and textbox, using REPLACE to replace the forward slashes with back slashes to trick the browser into fixing an invalid URL, etc. Nothing seems to work. Will look into the servername:port as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle the Hyperlink clicked event for your reportviewer control:

Assign the handler in your reportviewer constructor

```
 YourReportViewerControl.Hyperlink += new HyperlinkEventHandler(YourReportViewerControl_Hyperlink);

void YourReportViewerControl_Hyperlink(object sender, HyperlinkEventArgs e)
        {
                e.Cancel = true;

                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Hyperlink);
        }
```